# Switching emulators in Android

Tags: android-emulator

I am using eclipse to develop Android apps.I have not found a way to switch emulators when running/debugging my project.Is there an easy way to switch between the emulators I have set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave all emulators you need running at the same time.

Then, when you run a project, Eclipse should ask you which emulator you want to use.

Comment: Hi Thanks.How do I turn them all on or make them all run at the same time.

Comment: In Eclipse, at the top, go to "Window" -> "Android SDK and AVD Manager". This should open a window with all AVD's listed, where you can select the AVD's and hit the "Start" button, one at a time.